# Question that cannot be answered?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question, accepted-answer, community-wiki

Can I have a question closed, or should I move it to community wiki, or...what's the best practice?

Specifically [Windows Update not working on Windows Server 2008 R2](https://serverfault.com/questions/355020/windows-update-not-working-on-windows-server-2008-r2), simply because there is no way to ever verify now if an answer is correct or not.

I don't want it to count against my acceptance ratio, since no one can technically ever "answer" the question now that I've had Microsoft support fix the issue. But on the other hand, I compiled a lot of steps together that aren't already compiled in one spot on the net, and motobói put a response with brand new content that after days of research, I hadn't ran cross before. It could be very helpful to the next person, so I don't want to just remove/delete the question either, even if no verifiable answer can be given at this point.

Answer (score 15):

Write your own answer explaining what you/Microsoft did and then accept it.

Comment: While a good idea in general, he already stated that he does not know what MS support did - and apparently the support reps are unable to tell concisely as well. Not sure if this makes a good "accepted answer".

Comment: We should have been told that above and not in a comment to an answer of on original question then ;)

Answer (score 1):

While very low accept rates tend to be frowned upon it would be quite unrealistic to expect everyone to have 100%.

I am actually concerned that those who have asked more than a few questions and do have 100% accept rate are not showing due diligence. The reason being that if all the questions can be answered definitively then the questions are a bit too easy, which to me indicates that the poster hasn't really tried very hard to solve the problem before posting the question. That is lazy and unprofessional and not the sort of person I would want to work with.

Also, not all problems have a solution, so some questions should never have an accepted answer unless that answer is a very good explanation of exactly why the solution doesn't exist.

In the case you are asking about what Iain's suggest is the perfect solution because you provide valuable information to others while maintaining your accept rate. You may well earn a few upvotes at the same time.